# iOS tab bar icons are blurry

Tags: ios, tabbar

My tab bar icons appear blurry.

[image]

I created the icons using Photoshop, and followed the iOS Human Interface Guidelines when I  decided the sizes of each icons.

e.g. icon size: 30x30px png

This only happens with the tab bar. I wonder if this happens because of the resolution of the images or because of programming issues...

Comment: Did you double the size of the images? 30x30 is for non-Retina devices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using icon size `30x30` which I assume is for `1x` (*iPhone<4*). Since *iPhone>=4* needs `2x` and `3x` images so you have to include that also.

Either you use images with naming conventions like

```
star.png     // 1x = 30x30
star@2x.png  // 2x = 60x60
star@3x.png  // 3x = 90x90
```

or you can use `image.xcassets` and put your `1x`, `2x` and `3x` images there and use it.

Reference [Xcode Assets Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

Probably because using a device with the retina screen.

Try about changing the icon's filename to xxx@2x.xxx like "facebook_icon@2x.png".

Answer (score 1):

Also, be aware that you can use a **PDF file** (vector graphics, resolution independent) instead of PNGs, and Xcode will render the appropriate resolutions at build time for you (I don't think you can easily do this for third party icons such as Facebook, but...).

To see how this is done, create a new project using the "Tabbed Application" template, and check the asset catalog for the tab bar icon images. It does just that for the circle and square icons of the "First" and "Second" initial tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code to set image for uitabbaritem in uitabbar .

```
tabbaritem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@“image”] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```